Lookup Field is not setting up in Test Class
I am having Anvil__DealerStockUnit__c object lookup with Account object. Whenever I am trying to create Anvil__DealerStockUnit__c  related to Account so only Anvil__DealerStockUnit__c  records are creating it is not taking Account Id in it.
Code -
Account account1 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account 1', Anvil__PrimaryStoreLocation__c = store_LocationOne.Id, OwnerId=currentUsrId, RecordTypeId= '01241000000zCS6AAM');
Account account2 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account 2', Anvil__PrimaryStoreLocation__c = store_LocationTwo.Id, OwnerId=currentUsrId, RecordTypeId= '01241000000zCS6AAM');



for( Integer i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    Anvil__DealerStockUnit__c inventory1 = new Anvil__DealerStockUnit__c();
    Integer j = math.mod(i,2);
    if(j==0)
    {
        inventory1.Name = 'Test DSU'+i;
        inventory1.Anvil__Account__c = accOne;
        inventory1.Anvil__Group__c = 'Hay';
        inventory1.Anvil__Hours_or_Units__c = '400';
        inventory1.Anvil__EquipmentMake__c = 'JOHN DEERE';
        inventory1.Anvil__EquipmentModel__c= '561M';
        inventory1.Washout_Cycle__c = 3;
        inventory1.Anvil__Date_Sold__c = Date.today().addMonths(-12);
        inventory1.RecordTypeId = '0122M000000viDxQAI';
        inventory1.Anvil__Previous_Owner__c = accTwo;
    }
    else
    {
        inventory1.Name = 'Test DSU'+i;
        inventory1.Anvil__Account__c = accTwo;
        inventory1.Anvil__Group__c = 'Tractor';
        inventory1.Anvil__Hours_or_Units__c = '700';
        inventory1.Anvil__EquipmentMake__c = 'MDS';
        inventory1.Anvil__EquipmentModel__c= 'SP-TLT-12S';
        inventory1.Washout_Cycle__c = 3;
        inventory1.Anvil__Date_Sold__c = Date.today().addMonths(-12);
        inventory1.RecordTypeId = '0122M000000viDyQAI';
        inventory1.Anvil__Previous_Owner__c = accOne;
    }
    dsuList.add(inventory1);
}

insert dsuList;

In List it is only storing Anvil__DealerStockUnit__c data not the Anvil__Account__c  and Anvil__Previous_Owner__c

You should never hardcode ids, you could get the RecordTypeId via getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName() of Schema.DescribeSObjectResult. As xouns said, just creating a new instance of Account record is not enough, you must insert them in your test method.

So first of all, you have not yet inserted these accounts. These do not exist in the Test context (tests run on an empty database). So you want to insert these before you insert the Anvil__DealerStockUnit__c records.
// insert accounts 
Account account1 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account 1', Anvil__PrimaryStoreLocation__c = store_LocationOne.Id, OwnerId=currentUsrId, RecordTypeId= '01241000000zCS6AAM'); 
Account account2 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account 2', Anvil__PrimaryStoreLocation__c = store_LocationTwo.Id, OwnerId=currentUsrId, RecordTypeId= '01241000000zCS6AAM');
List<Account> testAccounts = new List<Account>{account1, account2};
insert testAccounts;

The you can reference the accounts in the creation of the child records. You may want to explicitly mention the Id field here. You can do this inside the for loop like below:
inventory1.Anvil__Account__c = testAccounts[j].Id;

Or before the for loop, like below:
// get the modulus
Integer j = math.mod(i,2);
// pre-create the account.
Anvil__DealerStockUnit__c inventory1 = new Anvil__DealerStockUnit__c(
    Name = 'Test DSU'+i,
    Anvil__Account__c = testAccounts[j].Id,
    Washout_Cycle__c = 3,
    Anvil__Date_Sold__c = Date.today().addMonths(-12),
    ...
);


I have inserted the accounts just not paste the code, also having the ids and I have printed the list 'dsuList' all the records are fetching including Anvil__Account__c but , when I am inserting this list 'dsuList' all data is inserting except 'Anvil__Account__c' this one , that is why it is not relating to account.
